# Match a char once not knowing its position

Tags: php, regex

I have to match the sql `LIKE` operator, which have `%` in its argument.
I want to get the argument of the operator, with no `%`, in php (PCRE regex)

My string to be matched can be something like

```
field LIKE %?
field LIKE ?%
field LIKE %?%
```

`?` is the argument that will be replaced.

My problem is that `%` can be at the right of `?`, or at its left, or both, I have to match it at least once.

I tried with `\s*(%?\?%?)` to match only the argument, but it works also with no `%`

Comment: because simply `\?` is not used with like query.. there should be atleast 1 `%` before and/or after according to OP.

Comment: What is the language/tool you are using the regex in? And can you give an example output you want to get after the replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `%(\?)|(\?)%`

Explanation:

- `%(\?)` looks for `%` left side (matches both %? and %?%)
- `(\?)%` looks for `%` right side (matches both ?% and %?%)

Covers all the cases required.

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lH5gY0/2)

EDIT:-

If you want to replace just `?` use `(?<=%)(\?)|(\?)(?=%)`

[DEMO with substitution](https://regex101.com/r/lH5gY0/3)